# How to make a GUI multithread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface

I am doing a monitor process in python which indicate the `pid`, the name and the memory used by a process.

How to use multi-threads for make a gui and synchonized with the interior methods which calculate the process information

```
class Monitor(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth = 0, background = "#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background = "#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient = "vertical", command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window = self.frame, anchor="nw",tags="self.frame")
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        self.tabla()

    def tabla(self):
        '''Put in some fake data'''
        proceso = Proceso()
        num_procesos = proceso.num_procesos()

        tk.Label(self.frame,text = "PID",width = 8, borderwidth = 1, relief = "solid").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        tk.Label(self.frame,text = "Nombre",width = 7, borderwidth = 1, relief = "solid").grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        tk.Label(self.frame,text = "Estado del proceso",width = 15, borderwidth = 1, relief = "solid").grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        tk.Label(self.frame,text = "Cache",width = 7, borderwidth = 1, relief = "solid").grid(row = 0, column = 3)
        tk.Label(self.frame,text = "Memoria",width = 15, borderwidth = 1, relief = "solid").grid(row = 0, column = 4)
        tk.Label(self.frame,text = "Disco",width = 7, borderwidth = 1, relief = "solid").grid(row = 0, column = 5)
        tk.Label(self.frame,text = "Acciones",width = 12, borderwidth = 1, relief = "solid").grid(row = 0, column = 6)

        killentrada = tk.Entry(self.frame,width = 7, borderwidth = 2, relief = "solid").grid(row  =1, column = 8)
        killboton = tk.Button(self.frame,text = "Matar proceso", width = 10, borderwidth = 2, relief = "solid",command = proceso.kill()).grid(row = 1, column = 7)

        for renglon in range(num_procesos+1):
            tk.Label(self.frame, text = proceso.pid(renglon-1),borderwidth="0",relief="solid").grid(row = renglon+1, column=0)
            tk.Label(self.frame, text = proceso.nombre(renglon-1)).grid(row = renglon+1, column=1)
            tk.Label(self.frame, text = proceso.estado(renglon-1)).grid(row = renglon+1, column=2)
            #tk.Label(self.frame, text = proceso.memoria(renglon-1)).grid(row = renglon+1, column=4)


    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: This tutorial might help: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.fr/2013/10/why-your-gui-app-freezes.html. You probably need to learn how to interact with Tkinter's mainloop when doing threading.

Comment: This looks good too http://pythonhosted.org/futures/. It allows you to do multi-threading in much nicer way.